# Parsing large string values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, database, string, parsing

Example of string I am working with:

`s = "{new {value1 value2 value3}} {old {value2 value1 value1}} {{old school} {value2 value3 value1}}"`

The {}'s are affected by spaces, which is why "old school" is surrounded while "new" and "old" are not.

Parsing the first two (new and old) are easily done using `s.split[1]` to access "new" and `s.split[3..5]` for the values. The problem comes when "new" or "old" has a space, in this case "old school". In the database I am accessing, these names with spaces occur randomly.

How can I alter my parsing to account for these occurrences?

Comment: Replace `{old school}` with `sch`

Comment: You haven't told us what output you want. The answers so far assume key/value pairs, but to me it looks hierarchical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this one line:

```
s.split("}} {").map{|x| x.split(" {")}.map{|x| x.map{|y| y.gsub("{","").gsub("}","")}}
```

Kind of ugly but works with your example, returns:

```
[["new", "value1 value2 value3"], ["old", "value2 value1 value1"], ["old school", "value2 value3 value1"]]
```

You can then parse if further by breaking values into their own objects etc. If you want it as hash, you can get it like this:

```
Hash[s.split("}} {").map{|x| x.split(" {")}.map{|x| x.map{|y| y.gsub("{","").gsub("}","")}}]
```

This will return:

```
{"new"=>"value1 value2 value3", "old"=>"value2 value1 value1", "old school"=>"value2 value3 value1"}
```

Comment: Actually the better solution.  Doesn't work though in case you allow `s = "{new value} {old {value2 value1 value1}}` ;-)

Comment: Of course, I am just targeting his specific example :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to parse this with regular expressions, you should rather go character by character and remember your position in there bracket hierarchy.

Here is a solution of mine: http://pastebin.com/kLLnS5qB

(That's only a rought cut, some calls aren't really dry and it lacks testing.)

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
[#<struct key="new", values=["value1", "value2", "value3"]>, #<struct key="old", values=["value2", "value1", "value1"]>, #<struct key="old school", values=["value2", "value3", "value1"]>]
```